# Put many function inside function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm newbie in Javascript and wanna learn function to make own plugin.

So first i'm learn about this:

```
(function() {
      // Define our constructor
      this.Cms = function(){
        this.Test = function()
        {
            return "Halo there";
        }
      };
    }());
var md = new Cms();
```

With that, I can access `md` variable and `Test` method successfully in browser console.

```
> md.Test()
< "Halo there"
```

I wanna make many function inside `Cms`, so I trying this:

```
(function() {
      // Define our constructor
      this.Cms = function(){
        this.Test = function()
        {
            return "Halo there";
        }

        this.TestAgain = function()
        {
            this.Helpme = function()
            {
                return "Heya";
            }
        }
      };
    }());
```

And execute `var md = new Cms.TestAgain()` in console, that returning error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cms.TestAgain is not a constructor at <anonymous>:1:10
```

My goal is make many function and each function can called in variable. For example I can declare `var md = new Cms.TestAgain()` and run function `md.Helpme()` that can return value `Heya`. Also I can declare `var md = new Cms()` and run function `md.TestAgain.Helpme()` with same return value `Heya`.

It's possible? Help me guys :)

Thanks.

Comment: You won't be able to reach `TestAgain` from `Cms` directly, you have to instanciate `Cms` first, something like this `var cms = new Cms(); var testAgain = new cms.TestAgain();`. That being said, this is a weird construction, and I don't understand your goal.

Comment: Take a look at the official documentation https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/.

Comment: Aah thaanks @leaf :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the function is called **Anonymous self executing function**.

Secondly, it is better to define your function the following way as the very well known library **jQuery** does:

```
(function(window) {
    // Define your function here
    var Cms = function () {
         // Function body
    };

    // Add the function to the window scope so that it can be accessed anywhere
   window.Cms = Cms;
})(window);
```

When you define functions like this:

```
var Cms = function () {
    this.test = function () {
        console.log("Hello");
    };

    this.testAgain = function() {
        console.log("Hello again");
    };
};
```

You have to call it like this:

```
// First create an object of Cms
var md = new Cms();

// Then call the methods
md.test(); // Hello
md.testAgain(); // Hello again
```

If you want another function in `testAgain`, you can do this way:

```
var Cms = function () {
    ...
    this.testAgain = function() {
        this.help = function() {
            console.log("help");
        };
    };
};

// Create object of Cms
var md = new Cms();

// Create object of testAgain
var x = new md.testAgain();

// Now call the function
x.help();
```

Here is the entire code snippet:

```
(function(window) {
    var Cms = function () {
         this.test = function () {
             console.log("Hello");
         };
         this.testAgain = function () {
             this.help = function() {
                 console.log("Help");
             };
         };
    };
    window.Cms = Cms;
})(window);

// Create the object
var md = new Cms();
// Call the function test
md.test(); // Hello

// Create the object of testAgain using object of Cms 
var x = new md.testAgain(); // Hello again

// Call the function help
x.help(); // Help
```

If you don't want to create objects and directly want to call `Cms.test()`, you can use JavaScript objects like this:

```
// Create a object
var Cms = {};
Cms.test = function() {
    console.log("Hello");
};

// Create a nested objects here
Cms.testAgain = {};

Cms.testAgain.help = () {
    console.log("Help");
};
```

And then call it directly as:

```
Cms.test(); // Hello
Cms.testAgain.help(); // Help
```

Notice that here you don't need the `new` operator.

Here is the entire code snippet:

```
(function(window) {
     var Cms = {};
     Cms.test = function () {
          console.log("Hello");
     };
     Cms.testAgain = {};
     Cms.testAgain.help = function () {
          console.log("Hello again");
     };

     window.Cms = Cms;
})(window);

// Directly call the functions
Cms.test(); // Hello
Cms.testAgain.help(); // Help
```

Above code is same as doing this:

```
(function(window) {
     var Cms = {
         test: function () {
             console.log("Hello");
         },
         testAgain: {
             help: function () {
                 console.log("Hello again");
             },
         },
     };

     window.Cms = Cms;
})(window);

// Directly call the functions
Cms.test(); // Hello
Cms.testAgain.help(); // Help
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thaank you for explanation. But it's possible to put function inside `test` or `testAgain`? So I can call it Cms.test.selectData() for example

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check. :)

Comment: Ahh thank you so much. Although it's different with my goal, but can help me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

In your functional code

```
(function() {
  // Define our constructor
  this.Cms = function() {
    this.Test = function() {
      return "Halo there";
    }
    this.TestAgain = function() {
      this.Helpme = function() {
        return "Heya";
      }
    }
  };
}());
```

every time when you create instance or object using new keyword it give access within function limit

For example on instance of Cms give you access on `Test` and `TestAgain`

```
var md = new Cms()
```

But for access `Helpme` you need to object of `TestAgain` which depend on `Cms` 
which is

```
const testAgain = new md.TestAgain()
```

Now you can freely call `Helpme` function on instance of testAgain

```
console.log(testAgain.Helpme())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword is intented to be used in conjunction with a class (a template for objects) like so:

```js
function Person (firstname, lastname) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
}

donald = new Person("Donald", "Trump");
barack = new Person("Barack", "Obama");
console.dir(donald);
console.dir(barack);
```

You don't need it here. Instead you could just write:

```
var cms = {
  testAgain: {
    helpme: function () { return "Heya"; }
  }
};
```

And later write:

```
cms.testAgain.helpme();
```